# HTA determine if the Printer is Installed and Inform the User

Tags: jscript, hta

```
    console.log(newPrinter);
    alert("Installing New Printer");
    var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var PrinterPath = "\\\\Server\\Printer";
    WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(PrinterPath);
    WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterPath);      
    var isInstalled = false;
    while(isInstalled = false)
    {
        var oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections();
        for(i = 0; i < oPrinters.length; i += 2) {
            alert("Port " + oPrinters.Item(i) + " = " + oPrinters.Item(i + 1));
            if(PrinterPath == oPrinters.Item(i))
            {
                isInstalled = true;
                alert("Finished Installing Printer");
            }
        }
    }
```

It installs the Printer but then takes several seconds to install the Printer and there is no notification or alert.

My alert UI never appears.

Comment: `console.log` in hta? Also, `while` loop here is an awful solution. Use `setInterval`, set the delay e.g. to 1 sec, and clear the interval when the printer is found.

Comment: @Teemu I usually use an older version of [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: @Teemu thanks can you post your solution? I don't understand how setInterval will help me? in my limited tests, I've encountered that sometimes the "AddWindowsPrinterConnection" doesn't work. When this happens, I am stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: An interval will check the success periodically, and lets the execution of other code as well as rendering the UI, without blocking the thread inside the while loop. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval